# Laravel Migration Error

Tags: laravel-5.3

I cant seem to work out why I am getting this error on this migration file?

Error

> [37;41m  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  ←[39;49m
>   ←[37;41m  Call to a member function nullable() on null             ←[39;49m

The date on the file is after the foreign id creation in the Customers table.This is laravel 5.3. How can I resolve this error?

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();           
        $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps('date_from')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps('date_to')->nullable();
        $table->date('invoice_date')->nullable();
        $table->date('due_at')->nullable();     
        $table->integer('total_charge')->nullable();
        $table->integer('rate')->nullable();
        $table->integer('total_hours')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('description', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('notes', 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('invoice_ref')->nullable();  

        $table->foreign('customer_id')
              ->references('id')->on('customers')
              ->onDelete('cascade');                      
    });
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `timestamp` method in this two lines...

```
$table->timestamp('date_from')->nullable();
$table->timestamp('date_to')->nullable();
```

`timestamps()` not accepts any argument and creates two colums : `created_at` and `updated_at` 
See [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Remove these two lines from your code

```
$table->timestamp('date_from')->nullable();
$table->timestamp('date_to')->nullable();
```

And only include this line for the timpstamping:

```
 $table->timestamps();
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace it like this - remove the `s` from timestamp:

```
$table->timestamp('date_from');
$table->timestamps('date_day');
```

Comment: Please check spelling